# select query in hql

Tags: hibernate, select, hql

I have a `Vendor` class corresponding to a `Vendor` table in my database, and I want to retrieve data from that table. When I use this:

```
Query q = s.createQuery("from Vendor ");
    java.util.Iterator itr = q.iterate();
    while (itr.hasNext()) {
        Vendor v = (Vendor) itr.next();
        System.out.println(v.getVendor Id() + " " + v.getVendorName() + " " + v.getVendorRating());
```

It works fine. But when I want to do the same using a `select` query:

```
Query q = s.createQuery("select v.vendorId, v.vendorName, v.venderRating from Vendor v");
    Iterator itr = q.iterate();
    while (itr.hasNext()) {
        Vendor v = (Vendor) itr.next();
        System.out.println(v.getVendorId() + " " + v.getVendorName() + " " + v.getVendorRating());
    }
```

an error is raised:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to
>   com.apple.hibernate.vendor.Vendor

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

```
"select v.vendorId, v.vendorName, v.venderRating from Vendor v"
```

will not return you a Vendor object but instead a `Object[]`, each item from the array is a column.

In your case, it should be something like:

```
Query q = s.createQuery("select v.vendorId, v.vendorName, v.venderRating from Vendor v");
    Iterator itr = q.iterate();
    while (itr.hasNext()) {
        Object[] v = (Object[]) itr.next();
        System.out.println(v[0] + " " + v[1] + " " + v[2]);
    }
```

The code is not tested so it may be somewhat faulty, but the logic is there.